# How to configure many to many to change the default configurations in EF Core 7.0

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I created this model in C#, the main goal is to create a very clean object without FKs and intermediate classes in the model.

```
[Table("Left")]
public class Left
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Right> Rights { get; set; }
}
[Table("Right")]
public class Right
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }


}
```

And added this this on OnModelCreating method

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Left>().HasMany(x => x.Rights).WithMany().UsingEntity(a => a.ToTable("LeftRight"));
```

And by consequence this was the migration that I got for the many to many table

```
migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
    name: "LeftRight",
    columns: table => new
    {
        LeftId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
        RightsId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
    },
    constraints: table =>
    {
        table.PrimaryKey("PK_LeftRight", x => new { x.LeftId, x.RightsId });
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_LeftRight_Left_LeftId",
            column: x => x.LeftId,
            principalTable: "Left",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
        table.ForeignKey(
            name: "FK_LeftRight_Right_RightsId",
            column: x => x.RightsId,
            principalTable: "Right",
            principalColumn: "Id",
            onDelete: ReferentialAction.Cascade);
    });
```

But I want to change the column name and the Delete Cascade, I tried this code but never got it to work and create the migration anymore, changed it many times and never got it right

```
 modelBuilder.Entity<Left>().HasMany(x => x.Rights).WithMany()
     .UsingEntity(
     j => j.HasOne("Left")
         .WithMany("Rights")
         .HasForeignKey("LeftId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
     j => j
         .HasOne("Right")
         .WithMany()
         .HasForeignKey("RightId").OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.NoAction),
     x =>
     {
         x.HasKey("LeftId", "RightId");
         x.ToTable("LeftRight");
     });
```

And this is the error that I got

```
The entity type 'Left (Dictionary<string, object>)' requires a primary key to be defined. If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in 'OnModelCreating'.
```

How should I add the OnModelCreating to get this result in migration

```
    migrationBuilder.CreateTable(
        name: "LeftRight",
        columns: table => new
        {
            LeftId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false),
            RightId = table.Column<int>(type: "int", nullable: false)
        },
        constraints: table =>
        {
            table.PrimaryKey("PK_LeftRight", x => new { x.LeftId, x.RightId });
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_LeftRight_Left_LeftId",
                column: x => x.LeftId,
                principalTable: "Left",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
            table.ForeignKey(
                name: "FK_LeftRight_Right_RightId",
                column: x => x.RightId,
                principalTable: "Right",
                principalColumn: "Id",
                onDelete: ReferentialAction.NoAction);
        });
```

Comment: _"very clean object without FKs "_ - eh, what?

Comment: @Dai I mean without adding an public int FKId to my class, that would only expose the model database and wouldn't help in development